# Multiple fonts in Ionic 2 application

Tags: sass, ionic2, webfonts

So I'm working on a hybrid web app using the Ionic 2 framework.  I'm coming up against a strange problem.

If I set

```
*{   
    font-family: 'bebas';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

In app.scss it shows the correct font for everything but when I try to include a second font in the app for button text like so

```
 .dash-button-sm{
    width: 4em;
    height: 6em;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    color:whitesmoke;
    font-size: 12px !important;
    text-transform: none !important;
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular' !important;
 }
```

It doesn't display the different font on my button.  My second font is in the same directory as the first one and I copy pasted the font-family declaration and changed the font file names to the correct ones.  I'm certain these are correct and this isn't the issue.

Also when inspecting in console the css appears to be using the second font but the display is clearly still the original font.

Has anyone else come up against this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your build file to include your new font, usually the "sass" and "fonts" tasks.

Check this link: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/extend-ionic2-add-custom-fonts-icons-ionic-config-json/48589

P.S - If you're already doing this and is not working please post the code fragments you're using.